# Classloader java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java

So I have a classloader loading a class like so:

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class cls = cl.loadClass("modules.Test");
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getModule", noparams);
Class<?> type = method.getReturnType();

if(type.newInstance() instanceof Module){
    System.out.println("Accessed field with type: Module");
}
```

The class `Module` is in another jar at runtime. And the `Test.class` was generated within that main jar then i unarchived it, so the dependency would be there.

How can I access other dependencies from the external .class file I have loaded?

The exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xxxxxxx/xxxx/objects/Module
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxxxxxx.xxxx.objects.Module
```

Comment: Does the JAR file contain a file called `modules/Test.class`?

Comment: Yes in my test the class file stayed in the main jar. But i plan to remove it after i pulled the generated Test.class out.

Comment: please indicate what was the exact exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is happening because your `modules.Test` class depends the `Modules` class, but your custom class loader can't find that class.

I think that is because you have instantiated the custom classloader incorrectly.  You wrote:

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
```

That creates a classloader whose parent classloader is the default system classloader.  But the error implies that the default classloader is not the one that knows about `Modules`.  Try this instead:

```
Classloader cl = new URLClassLoader(
        urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

This should at least give you a classloader that knows about `Modules`.

---

Note: adding the URL for the JAR containing `Modules` to the `urls` array is a non-solution.  You are liable to end up loading the `Modules` class twice, and that is liable to lead to other problems.  (The `instanceof` won't work, for example.)