# NoClassDefFoundError with URLClassLoader

Tags: java

I want to load a class on my local file system,so I try to use the URLClassloader to do it,and Here is my code

```
public void testDynamaicLoader() throws Exception {      
    String path = "D://temp";
    String repository = (new URL("file", null,
        path+File.separator)).toString();
    URL[] urls = new URL[1];
    URLStreamHandler streamHandler = null;
    urls[0] = new URL(null, repository,streamHandler);
    URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    loader.loadClass("com.MyService");
}
```

The target class MyService is in the path of
    `D:/temp/com/`
and it's in the package `com`
But when I run my test method I get the error information follows

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/MyService
```

I have no idea why this happened,help me please,Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the `com.MyClass` is set in your classpath when executing the program.

Comment: The *complete* stacktrace will probably give you hints as to why the `loadClass` call failed.

Comment: It is more accurately a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28143017/207421).